# Why does my index not increment in setInterval?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, increment

I am trying to make a typewriter mechanism in React. In props, I have an array of 8 strings, each containing a sentence. I am trying to render them in sequence in a paragraph as follows:

First, I create an array of sentences. Every letter is assigned to `letters` variable. Then I change a state by adding every letter from the `sentence`. When length of letters and sentence is equal I want to increment the `index`, to switch to the next sentence. But it doesn't work. The problem is that it only renders the first sentence.

The error in console is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`.

Here is my code:

```
componentDidMount(){    
   this.time = setTimeout(()=>{
            this.intervalSec = setInterval(()=>{
                sentence = [...this.props.msgSec[index]]
                letters += [...sentence[letters.length]]
                if( letters.length < sentence.length){
                    this.setState({
                        text2: letters,
                        span: "inline"
                    })
                } else if(letters.length == sentence.length){
                    index++
                }
            }, this.props.interval)           
        },this.props.interval * this.props.msgFirst.length )   
}
```

Comment: Where are you defining index, sentence and letters?

Comment: @Rodius sorry, I forgot to copy that part, I define index, sentence, letters above the setTimeout() in componentDidMount()

Comment: Your second statement is also an if, so if that condition is never met, it will never increment. Use just else instead?

Comment: @G_V Unfortunetly, it doesn't work. Still have this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object and the sentence doesn't change.

Comment: Have you checked `letters += [...sentence[letters.length]]` does what you expect?

Comment: @RaphaMex Yes I have. It adds next letter every interval.

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty to write my own function of what I believe you wanted to make. You have to add the functionality that works for your app but the loop and line interval is working if I'm not mistaken. See if it works for you:

```js
const sentences = ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop', 'qrst', 'uvwxyz'];
const letters = [];
let index = 0;

setInterval(() => {
      letters.push(sentences[index][letters.length]);
      if (letters.length > sentences[index].length) {
        console.log("next line");
        letters.length = 0;
        index++;
      } else {
        console.log('letters:', letters);
      }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know what was the problem, I didn't clear the variable `letters` in each interval. Now, when I added to `else {index++; letters = ""}` is working fine.